# Javascript methods recalling and printing

Tags: javascript, function, variables, methods

I'm studying JavaScript and I've some problems with the recall of functions...

These are my two functions:
the first:

```
function geisson() {
    var iabile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    iabile.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (iabile.readyState == 4) {
            var objectjson = {};
            var arrayCards = []; //creazione dell'array che conterrà le cards
            objectson = JSON.parse(iabile.responseText);
            arrayCards = objectson.cards;
            var Ettore = []; //Vèttore di cards

            //the results
            for (i = 0; i < arrayCards.length; i++)
                document.getElementById('image').src = "http://www.mysite.com/png/public/card/" + arrayCards[i].__guid__ + "?width=292";
        }
    }
    iabile.open("GET", "gnekcard.json", true);
    iabile.send(null);
}
```

and the second function:

```
function Entity() {
    var iabile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    iabile.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (iabile.readyState == 4) {
            var objectjson = {};
            var arrayCards = []; //creazione dell'array che conterrà le cards
            objectson = JSON.parse(iabile.responseText);
            arrayCards = objectson.cards;
            //the results
            for (i = 0; i < arrayCards.length; i++)
                document.getElementById('informazioni').innerHTML += "\r\n" + "Nome : " + arrayCards[i].__title__ + "\r\n" + "Vanity url: " + arrayCards[i].vanity_urls[0] + "\r\n";
        }
    }
    iabile.open("GET", "gnek.json", true);
    iabile.send(null);
}
```

I would like to have a third function that prints the results of the other 2 functions. I'd  prefer to have the "for" in only in the third function and recall the vectors of the others methods but they aren't global. I don't want to have global variables (if possible) so how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

In the `geisson` function you can do this:

```
geisson.arrayCards = arrayCards;
```

and you can do the same in the `Entity` function

```
Entity.arrayCards = arrayCards;
```

Then you can create a third function that can access the `arrayCards` of each function.

```
function displayArrayCards {
  var geissonCards = geisson.arrayCards;
  var EntityCards = Entity.arrayCards;
  var i;
  for(i = 0; i < geissonCards.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById('image').src = "http://www.mysite.com/png/public/card/" + geissonCards[i].__guid__ + "?width=292";
  }
  for(i = 0; i < EntityCards.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById('informazioni').innerHTML += "\r\n" + "Nome : " + EntityCards[i].__title__ + "\r\n" + "Vanity url: " + EntityCards [i].vanity_urls[0] + "\r\n";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do what you should always do when you work with Ajax calls: Use callbacks.

For example:

```
function geisson(callback) {
    var iabile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    iabile.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (iabile.readyState == 4) {
            // ...
            callback(objectson.cards);
        }
    }
    iabile.open("GET", "gnekcard.json", true);
    iabile.send(null);
}
```

and in your third function:

```
function someName() {
    geisson(function(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            //... do something with data ...
        }
    });
    // call Entity the same way here...
}
```

---

Btw, in your first function, you always override the `src` property of the *same* element (`document.getElementById('image')`). It does not make sense to iterate over the whole array here, sine eventually, `src` will have the value related to the last element. Either assign the values to multiple elements or just get the last element in the array.